# Bitwise operations on strings Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a large string of hex numbers, on which I want to perform some bitwise operations. I am trying to extract different bytes from it and then to apply bitwise OR, AND, XOR operations. Unfortunately, I don't know an easy way to do that, so every time I want to perform bitwise operations I am converting the hex into an integer. This is a simplified code.

```
data = "0x4700ff1de05ca7686c2b43f5e37e6dafd388761c36900ab37"

hex_data = "0x" + data[20:32]
four_bytes = hex_data[:10]
fifth_byte = "0x" + hex_data[10:12]
lshift_fourb = hex(int(four_bytes, 16) << 1)
bitwise_or_res = hex(int(lshift_fourb, 16) | int(fifth_byte, 16))
```

Is there an easy way to omit the constant conversion to integer and hex back and forth in order to do the same operations. I prefer to use either hex or binary since I need to extract certain bytes from the input data string and the `hex(int(hex_number, 16))` seems a bit too repetitive and tedious. If I don't convert it to an integer, Python is complaining that it cannot execute the `|` or `^` on strings.

Comment: Convert the string to an integer *once*, then do all operations in the integer domain, and only convert back to a string *once* at the end.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Integer, however, doesn't support slicing, thus calculating hex_data and four_bytes would have to be calculated with modulo. Possible, but tedious as well

Comment: but how I am supposed to extract specific bytes from an integer?

Comment: By shifting and masking.

Comment: You could also try converting the data to a `bytes` object, but I'm not sure if this will be easier in the end.

Comment: You can also write a few helper functions to factor out the repetitive stuff.

Comment: @mkrieger1 but isn't it possible to work only with hex numbers: `0xff ^ 0x1a` is a valid expression in Python. But when I try `hex(a) | hex(b)` where `a = "0xff"` and `b =  "0x1a"` gives me an error that I cannot execute bitwise operations on strings.

Comment: because the result of "hex" is a string.

Comment: in that case does really shifting and masking and working with integer will save me some writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
data = "0x4700ff1de05ca7686c2b43f5e37e6dafd388761c36900ab37"
size = (len(data)-2)//2
data_bytes = int(data,16).to_bytes(size,byteorder='big')
```

Now you can do this:

```
data_bytes[4] & data_bytes[5]
```

Comment: this seems to work, but I don't know why, when I print `data_bytes` it gives me `b'+C\xf5\xe3~m'` I am expecting something like `b'\x2b\x43\xf5\xe3\x7e\x6d` and also how I can extract the first 4 bytes from `data_bytes`. I am also not able to perform bitwise operations on bytes and integers, so I need either to convert the bytes to integers or convert the integers to bytes.

Comment: I have understood why the format of the data_bytes, I need to print them with `.hex()` at the end, otherwise, it is trying to match the ASCII codes.

Comment: I mean when I try to execute `data_byte[3] << bytes(1)` it gives me an error that the left shift operation is not supported for 'bytes' objects.

Comment: As a workaround I need to convert the bytes to integers using `int.from_bytes(data_bytes, byteorder="big")` in order to perform the bitwise left or right shift.

Comment: at least on my machine, printing `data_bytes` produces the desired result. Note that I've edited the code in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I have figured out that the single division outputs a float instead of an integer. I guess this is the only change you have done. I am testing it on a Python3.7 so maybe they have changed there something with the representation of this module.

Comment: not the only change. the other change was to make sure size is computed correctly

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the problem is that strings of hex digits are more readable and good for slicing and at least some shifting operations, but don't support bitwise operations. On the other hand, integers support bitwise operations but no slicing. The closest to what you want may be to create a custom class implementing both features (doing conversion whenever needed). This won't save you from implementing (and executing) the more complex code, but the rest of your application may be more readable because the conversions are "hidden".

Comment: exactly my point. Hex is perfect for slicing but then I need to convert it all the time in order to execute bitwise operations.